# Powershell XML: Attributes present, or not, changes how to get the Value

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm using Powershell 3.0, on a Windows 8 PC.  I have simple XML files with content like this (without the foobar part, that comes later):

```
<MyData>
    <Version>1.2a</Version>
    <Version foobar="1">3.4b</Version>
    <Version>5.6c</Version>
</MyData>
```

Now, I have been extracting all the versions into an array doing this:

```
[xml] $FileData = Get-Content .\thefile.xml
[array]$theVersions = $FileData.MyData.Version | % {$_}
```

All has been working fine, **until** I added the `foobar="1"` to the XML file -- which seems to break everything.  I've dug around a bit, and have tried things involving #text and InnerText:

```
[array]$theVersions = $FileData.MyData.Version | % {$_.'#text'}
```

But this **only works** for the **one piece** with the foobar; the other two seem invisible.  Naturally, I *could* add some (any) attribute to all of the data in the file, but that is not a workable solution.

**My Question:** Is there a **consistent way** to read the Value (or #text, or InnerText, whatever you prefer to call it) out of those XML nodes *whether or not* an attribute is present? Indeed, the presence or lack of an attribute needs to be considered UNKNOWN to my script.

FOLLOW-UP: Thanks to Keith's suggestion, and a little tweaking, I was able to use Select-XML to overcome my problem. As I do need that attribute when present (I had left that detail out initially as I didn't think it mattered), I ended up with something formatted like this:

```
[xml] $FileData = Get-Content .\thefile.xml
[array]$theVersions = (Select-Xml $FileData -XPath '//MyData/Version').Node | % {if ($_.foobar -ne $null) { "$($_.'#text') And Foobar $($_.foobar)"} else {$_.'#text'} }
$theVersions
```

And the resulting output:

```
1.2a
3.4b And Foobar 1
5.6c
```

Thanks, everyone! Hope this question, and the solution, helps someone else!

Comment: Have you looked at the Select-XML cmdlet? It uses xpath to get values. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx

Comment: I haven't tried Select-XML at all in my script(s), be it for this or other data-gathering from XML. I can start researching that, though it might have a bigger impact on existing scripts than I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Select-Xml`, here is how you would do it:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<MyData>
  <Version>1.2a</Version>
  <Version foobar="1">3.4b</Version>
  <Version>5.6c</Version>
</MyData>
'@

(Select-Xml $xml -XPath '//Version/text()').Node.Value
```

That will find any element named `Version`, if you want to limit it to just the elements under `MyData` change the XPath to `/MyData/Version/text()`.  This assumes that `MyData` is the root/doc element.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just filter for strings...

```
PS C:\Users\TMTech> [xml]$testxml = @"
<MyData>
    <Version>1.2a</Version>
    <Version foobar="1">3.4b</Version>
    <Version>5.6c</Version>
</MyData>
"@

PS C:\Users\TMTech> $Versions = $testxml.MyData.Version | ?{$_.GetType().Name -eq "String"}

PS C:\Users\TMTech> $Versions
1.2a
5.6c
```

Comment: But you see, that's what I'm trying to avoid - segmenting the results.  In the end, I want to be able to do `$Versions` and have it spit out the full list:  1.2a  3.4b  5.6c  (cannot seem to put on separate lines in this reply)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PoSh will "helpfully" give the `InnerText` as string directly when no attributes are present, but will give you an `XmlElement` when attributes are present.

One generic way, *other* that using `Select-Xml` or type checking is to force PoSh to always give to the innermost element as `XmlElement`:

```
[array]$theVersions = $FileData.MyData.GetElementsByTagName('Version').InnerText | % {$_}
```

By using `GetElementsByTagName` for the innermost element being accessed, you force the return type to `XmlElement` and then can uniformly access `InnerText.`